# How to run R script in Heroku?

Tags: r, heroku, plumber

I have created a analytics project which has three files. One is data, another is model and other is plumber run script. I am calling my model from plumber to expose my model to my Java program. 
Now, I need to deploy my R project to heroku or aws to hit the endpoints. 
I used a heroku-buildpack-r and am able to deploy the code. **But the plumber script is not getting called**. ***I don't know if the scripts are read automatically or I have to call them from somewhere manually.***
Can you guys please give me any idea of how to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: I'd encourage you to use one of the other hosting methods described here instead of trying to host on Heroku: https://www.rplumber.io/docs/hosting.html

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. That link turned out to be very helpful. I was able to deploy as docker image.